# Showing fields are algebraically closed

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots

Let K be a field, and let P be separable and irreducible over K. Let L be a splitting field of P over K.

I want to show that the fields K(u) and K(v) are isomorphic, where u and v are roots of P, and then extend this isomorphism.

I have shown that they are isomorphic, but to extend I need to show that K(u) and K(v) are algebraically closed - I was wondering could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: In general, this is simply not the case. Consider $K=\Bbb Q$, $P=X^2-2$. Then $L=K(u)=K(v)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Have you correctly understood the term "Algebraically closed"?